# Performance difference between spark local and spark cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark to train GBTs using MLLIB. For this task, I am confused if I should go for 1 powerful node with 32 cores, 100GB RAM in spark local mode using *--master local[4]*  or have a cluster of 4 nodes with 8 cores,20GB each in cluster standalone mode. Which would finish the task at hand faster and why?

Does using *--master local[4]* actually create as many executors/workers as in the cluster mode?

I am aware that in cluster mode, I would have the option to choose better resource managers such as YARN and MESOS so that would be one benefit but lets say I just want to compare local vs cluster standalone mode performance metrics.

Comment: I've got the very same question. Did you ever discovered any major advantages/disadvantages of local vs. cluster?

Comment: I ended up using spark local mode but I switched to using H2O for the GBM model. H2O is super fast and has better precision too, as compared with MLLIB.